# Retrieve Two Values Of A Row In One Query

Tags: javascript, sql, database, uitableview, appcelerator

So, what I'm trying to do is populate a table, in this case called `entity_info`, with information from an SQL database. I need two values from the table in order to do this, `entity_category` and `entity_name`.

Whilst populating the table, I do something like this:

```
var rows = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT entity_name FROM entity_info');
var rows2 = db.execute('SELECT entity_category FROM entity_info');

while (rows.isValidRow()) {
    //herp derp herp creating a table...
    var name = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : rows.fieldByName('entity_name'),
        color : '#666',
        left : '50dp',
        font : {
            fontSize : 22,
            fontWeight : 'bold',
            fontFamily : 'Arial'
        },
        backgroundColor : '#fff'
    });
    var category = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : rows2.fieldByName('entity_category'),
        color : '#666',
        left : '60dp',
        top : '40dp',
        font : {
            fontSize : 13,
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
            fontStyle : 'italic'
        }
    });
    rows.next();
    rows2.next();
}
```

But, that doesn't work for my purposes because it splits the two statements up and messes the ordering of the name to category matching. So, what I need to do is take one request (and just use the single `rows` variable), and then use that for the while statement and setting the text of each label.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try combining the SQL statements in rows and rows2?

```
var rows: db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT entity_name, entity_category FROM entity_info');
```

And just use rows as is.